# Наследование private полей

Tags: c++, наследование

Наследуются ли `private` поля базового класса дочерними?

Comment: что вы понимаете под этим?

Comment: @Grundy их ведь нельзя использовать, но формально они наследуются?

Comment: Да, они наследуются, но доступа к ним из наследника нет

Comment: @Grundy а в чём смысл тогда наследования этого?

Comment: private / protected исключительно защита кода от шаловливых рук программистов, чтобы внутренние механизмы/настройки не были испорчены из вне или в наследнике

Comment: С одной стороны защита, А с другой - кому надо, тот найдёт способ испортить. Наверное для всех языков ООП есть способы доступа к приватным полям базового класса разной степени нелегальности. Рефлексии, РТТИ всякие

Comment: @Sergey Зачем так сложно? Достаточно подчистить объявление класса в .h-файле :)

Comment: зачем подчищать? просто `#define private public`. Другое дело, что компилятор может рассчитывать, что к приватным полям не могут получить доступ извне и немного "оптимизировать". И как результат, всякие RTTI могут работать "странно".

Answer (score 5):

По существу - в с++ нет "полей" и "методов". Есть переменные класса и функции класса. Можно прошерстить стандарт и там нигде не упоминается о методах.

Они наследуются (то есть, в составе дочернего класса они есть), но прямого доступа к ним нет. Но если в базовом классе будут функции, которые к ним обращаются и эти функции класса будут public/protected, то этими приватными переменнымы класса  можно  будет "управлять", то есть, изменять, читать (естественно, в пределах возможностей нужных функций).